# How do you open the settings dialog in a Windows desktop gadget programmatically?

Tags: windows-desktop-gadgets

The Windows desktop gadget I'm developing requires some configuration on first run, so when it detects that it hasn't been configured, I want to immediately open the settings dialog. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not supported. It's a better user experience to pick some good defaults using [`System.Gadget.Settings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723661%28VS.85%29.aspx), and then let your user change them in the settings dialog. Forcing a user to pick some settings is not great for any application's first run experience.

Comment: I would agree, except that the gadget I'm developing needs to know the person's username on the server it's connecting to before it can display any useful information. So I guess I'll have it display a message asking the user to open the settings dialog.